# Read next and previous lines while reading file line-by-line

Tags: python, for-loop, io

Using Python, I want to read some file line-by-line and if a line matches some criteria, I want return the previous and next lines. What is the best (most pythonic) way to do it? I want do something like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.find("some string") != -1:
            print get_previous_line
            print get_next_line
```

---

**EDIT:**

It turns out that I need to read the **previous line** too, and there is no `previous` function. Question title and script modified accordingly...

Comment: use `next(f)` or `f.next()`

Comment: I totally did not know about `next()`! But doesn't for loop skip the next line if I call `next()`?

Comment: Note that in some cases it will be easier to simply use `for line in f.read().split('\n'):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
active = False
previous = None
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        prev = previous #this is the previous line now
        previous = line 
        if active: #active contains previous line ...
           do_something_with_line_after_some_string(prev,line) #terrible function name but you get the idea
        elif line.find("some string") != -1:
           active = line
           continue
        active = False
```

is a slightly better design pattern imho ... really there are other more pythonic ways to do this, depending on what this is actually doing ...

Comment: Looks good, but it turns out that I need to read the previous line too. Is there any way I can access the previous line?

Comment: is this something that will occure many times in one file or just once in a file?

Comment: many times. I just put `print` but I want to extract some lines from a file.

Comment: I think your code stores the line containing "some string" as a previous line (`active`), but I want one line before that...

Comment: there now its the previous line